# Setup React application with React router to navigate components and URL rewrite to navigate sub applications in IIS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting

I have a requirement where the root application (React + .NET core), for example - (example.com) has several components (myapp, dualapp) and React-Router is set to route to the components (example.com/myapp, example.com/dualapp).

At the same time, i have two sub applications (React + .NET core), for example - (example1.com, example2.com). I would like to route to sub applications by using example.com/example1, example.com/example2 but the my current Router setup is redirecting example.com/example1 to the React Router and looking for the component in the root application.

Can you please help on how to set up IIS rewrite to redirect to sub applications.

My current IIS Rewrite setup is given below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="example1" stopProcessing="false">
                  <match url="example1/(.*)" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.example1.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
              </rule>
              <rule name="example2" stopProcessing="false">
                  <match url="example2/(.*)" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.example2.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and the React-Router setup is given below,

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/myapp">
            <Myapp />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dualapp">
            <DualApp />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: URL rewite is a feature module to set url at server level. When request get into application router, IIS can do nothing. Request ->IIS ->url rewrite ->react-router ->react application ->response. So it is no use to set in url rewrite.